# onTagDiscovered not being called

Tags: nfc, sony-xperia

We have a proprietary NFC Card that contains medical information. We developed an app that registers for onTagDiscovered(). On the phone it was developed for, Sony Xperia X, Android 7.0 the routine is called when the card is placed next to the phone, but on a  Sony XA1 (Model G3121), Android 7.0, Kernel 4.4.15+ (8/09/2017 7:36:35 CST), Build Number 40.0.A.6.135 the routine is not called for our card but is for normal credit cards. (Also the phone beeps)

The card has it's own functions and is not by definition a Tag. But we use:
NfcA nfcA = NfcA.get(tag);
to get a NfcA structure from which we send and receive proprietary commands to the sim chip. Here is how we enable the Card: (Has anything changed???)

```
public static int READER_FLAGS =
        NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_V | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A| NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK;

private void enableReaderMode() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Enabling reader mode");
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(activity);
    if (nfc != null) {
        nfc.enableReaderMode(activity, mSIKeyCardReader, READER_FLAGS, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: possibly related to this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37125844

Comment: Is the tag detected in other tag reader apps? Maybe the tag does not receive sufficient power or the tag antenna does not match well enough with the reader antenna of the XA1.